# "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int" in CASE statement

Tags: sql-server

The following query is returning the aforesaid error. The column WNT.USER.PriviligeLevel_SV contains values 1,2,3 or different errors. I need to have the query return 'Administrator' if the value is 1, 'Guest' if the value is 2 and 'User' if the value is 3. Otherwise this column should contain the verbatim error message. I have tried to use `ELSE CAST([Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] AS nvarchar)` and  `WHEN [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` but neither is working. Please advice.

```
SELECT [Wnt.User.Host] AS 'Machine Name',
         "Account Privilege Level" =
         CASE 
              When [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] = 1 Then 'Administrator'
              When [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] = 2 Then 'User'
              When [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] = 3  Then 'Guest'
              Else [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV]
              End 
  FROM [Prod].[AdHoc].[TestBuffer]
```

SQL Version is 2008 and the WNT.USER.PriviligeLevel_SV column is defined as nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have different datatypes returned by different branches of the same `CASE` in SQL Server. (This is also true even if a branch will not get executed)

*Due to [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) rules of SQL Server the `VARCHAR` values get forced into `INT` which fails.*

You should cast your value from the `Else`-Branch to `NVARCHAR` (or `VARCHAR`) to have all branches of the `CASE` return the same datatype.

I.e. `Else CAST([Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty simple:

```
SELECT [Wnt.User.Host] AS 'Machine Name',
     "Account Privilege Level" =
     CASE 
          When [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] = '1' Then 'Administrator'
          When [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] = '2' Then 'User'
          When [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV] = '3'  Then 'Guest'
          Else [Wnt.User.PrivilegeLevel_SV]
          End 
FROM [Prod].[AdHoc].[TestBuffer]
```

You need to make sure you enclose numbers in single quotes if your column type is varchar.

Comment: No, the problem is not the values `evaluated by`, but the values `returned from` the case statement.

Comment: A case statement will search the whole table for a match, so when the comparison of an int and a varchar arises, an error is thrown. There's nothing wrong with the values returned by, since these are all string types.

Comment: No actually SQL Server is just fine comparing varchar to ints as long as they are parsable. Consider [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21535) and [that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8) for example. (this fails due to different return types while that succeeds)

Comment: We must be using two completely different languages then, because implicit comparisons between ints and varchars has always thrown an error for me. "That" isn't working by the way.

Comment: Oh sorry, must have mixed up links: [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21535) should fail and [that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21536) should not.